# "Error: No credentialStore settings found"

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have my Hyperledger Fabric network deployed on AWS, all the credentials and users are there so I just have to use the existing credentials and keys but when I put them in my ConnectionProfile.json I keep getting this error: "Error: No credentialStore settings found" and there's no logs in the peer. This is how my ConnectionProfile looks:

```
{
"name": "myClient",
    "version": "1.0",
    "clients":{
        "User1@mypeer.my-chain.com" : {
            "created": true,
            "client" : {
                "organization" : "myOrg",
                "credentialStore" : {
                    "<key-digested>_sk": "-----PRIVATE KEY-----",
                    "cryptoStore" : {
                        "<cryptostore-key-digested>_sk": "-----PRIVATE KEY-----"
                    }
                },
                "clientPrivateKey": "-----PRIVATE KEY-----",
                "clientSignedCert": "-----CERTIFICATE-----"
            }
        }

    },

    "channels" : {
        "myChannel" : {
            "orderers" : [ "orderer.coldor.my-chain.com" ],
            "peers" : {
                "mypeer" : {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "organizations" :{
        "myOrg" : {
            "mspid" : "myOrgMSP",
            "peers" : [ "mypeer.my-chain.com" ],
            "certificateAuthorities": "ca.mypeer.my-chain.com-cert.pem",
            "adminPrivateKey" : {
                "<adminkey-digested>_sk" : "-----PRIVATE KEY-----"
            },
            "signedCert" : {
                "pem" : "-----CERTIFICATE-----"
            }
        }

    },

    "orderers":{

        "orderer.coldor.my-chain.com" : {
            "url" : "grpc://my-url:7050",
            "grpcOptions" : {
                "ssl-target-name-override" : "orderer.coldor.my-chain.com",
                "grpc-max-send-message-length" : 5000
            },
            "tlsCACerts" : {
                "pem" : "-----CERTIFICATE-----"
            }
        }

    },

    "peers" : {
        "mypeer" : {
            "url" : "grpc://my-url:7051",
            "event-url" : "grpc://my-url:7053",
            "grpcOptions" : {
                "ssl-target-name-override" : "mypeer"
            },
            "tlsCACerts" : {
                "pem" : "-----CERTIFICATE-----"
            } 
        }
    }
```

}

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Any answer on that?